# Series/inequalities proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing

Suppose that $\{x_m\}$ is a sequence of positive, non-zero numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {x_n}$ diverges, and let $S_n = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$. Prove the following:

(i) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{1 + x_n}$ diverges.

(ii) For all $m, n \geq 1$, $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{x_{m + j}}{S_{m + j}} \geq 1 - \frac{S_m}{S_{m + n}}$

(iii) For all $n \geq 2$, $\frac{x_n}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{S_nS_{n-1}}$

My attempt:

(i) We check using the convergence/divergence tests:

Divergence test: Consider the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{1 + x_n}$. Does this limit $\neq 0$? Inconclusive.

Direct Comparison Test: Is $x_n \leq \frac{x_n}{1 + x_n}$? This only happens if $1 \leq \frac{1}{1 + x_n} \implies 1 \geq 1 + x_n$. This is false for $n \geq 1$ as $x_n$ is non-negative.

Ratio test: Consider the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{\frac{x_{n+1}}{1 + x_{n+1}}}{\frac{x_{n}}{1 + x_{n}}}| = |\frac{x_{n+1}(1 + x_n)}{(1 + x_{n+1})x_n}|$. Inconclusive.

Root test: Consider the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} {|\frac{x_{n}}{(1 + x_{n})}|}^{1/n}$. Inconclusive.

(ii) No idea how to do this one.

(iii) Consider the elementary sum $S_n - S_{n-1}$:

$$S_n - S_{n-1} = (x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n) - (x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{n-1}) = x_n$$

Notice that because $x_n$ are non-negative, we have that

$$S_n \geq S_{n-1} \implies S_n^2 \geq S_nS_{n-1} \implies \frac{1}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{1}{S_nS_{n-1}} \implies \frac{x_n}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{x_n}{S_nS_{n-1}} \implies \frac{x_n}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{S_nS_{n-1}}$$

For the ones I attempted, are they correct? Despite trying for the last few hours to use what I have learned thus far, I still cannot figure out how to go about proving (i) and (ii) ones? Any hints or assistance are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (i) separate two cases: If $x_n>1/2$ infinitely often then $x_n/(1+x_n)$ does not tend to zero. Otherwise $x_n/(1+x_n) \ge  x_n/(3/2)$ for all large enough $n$.
For (ii) replace $S_{m+j}$ on LHS by $S_{m+n}$ to reduce the sum.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Could you elaborate on your point about (ii)? How would replacing it work?

Comment: Actually, nevermind! I understood. Thanks again!